# iOS App Crash with pthread_kill

Tags: ios, crash

I have the following crash report but I can't figure out the cause of this crash. This crash appears quite frequently but the pattern varies at each time. Many thanks!

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x0000000198337270 __pthread_kill + 8
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x00000001982aeb18 abort + 112
2 libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x00000001983723e4 <redacted> + 0
3 libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x00000001983712f8 <redacted> + 192
4 CoreFoundation 0x00000001866c55e8 <redacted> + 192
5 CoreFoundation 0x00000001865d1394 CFRelease + 328
6 CoreFoundation 0x00000001866bc2bc _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 272
7 Foundation 0x0000000187502448 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 172
8 0x000000010020f088 _mh_execute_header + 1536136
9 0x0000000100225614 _mh_execute_header + 1627668
10 0x00000001001ac6d0 _mh_execute_header + 1132240
11 CFNetwork 0x00000001861745b8 <redacted> + 80
12 CFNetwork 0x0000000186174548 <redacted> + 208
13 CFNetwork 0x00000001861746c4 <redacted> + 60
14 CFNetwork 0x0000000186047990 <redacted> + 104
15 CFNetwork 0x000000018611150c <redacted> + 104
16 CFNetwork 0x0000000186033ac8 <redacted> + 76
17 CoreFoundation 0x00000001865d4cdc CFArrayApplyFunction + 68
18 CFNetwork 0x0000000186033974 <redacted> + 136
19 CFNetwork 0x0000000186033828 <redacted> + 312
20 CFNetwork 0x0000000186033654 <redacted> + 68
21 CoreFoundation 0x00000001866ac240 <redacted> + 24
22 CoreFoundation 0x00000001866ab4e4 <redacted> + 264
23 CoreFoundation 0x00000001866a9594 <redacted> + 712
24 CoreFoundation 0x00000001865d52d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
25 GraphicsServices 0x000000018fc9b6fc GSEventRunModal + 168
26 UIKit 0x000000018b19afac UIApplicationMain + 1488
27 0x000000010024bf1c _mh_execute_header + 1785628
28 libdyld.dylib 0x000000019821ea08 <redacted> + 4
```

Comment: You need to provide a properly symbolicated crash report and the corresponding source that is referenced in your app. The report should not show any `_mh_execute_header` lines or `<redacted>`.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you download some information from the web and are trying to create a string with some parts of that information:

```
6 CoreFoundation 0x00000001866bc2bc _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 272
7 Foundation 0x0000000187502448 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 172
```

Where ever you are using information that you fetched from the Internet, you should first check if that information is valid and respects the right format you expect. Therefore, I recommend you to validate the information before using it.

Answer (score 0):

this might help you:
[iPhone app crash at [NSString stringWithFormat]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487042/iphone-app-crash-at-nsstring-stringwithformat)

the error line must be:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@...",a,b...];
```